# PyQGIS - how to override maximum number of features in combobox

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, combo-box

Is there a simple way, how to override a maximum number of displayed features in QgsFeatureListComboBox? It seems that there is a hardcoded limit set to 100 features (in QgsFeatureFilterModel).

QgsFeatureListComboBox fits my needs almost perfectly except that limit. In most cases, there is small number of features to show. But sometimes, I have little over 100 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem that this issue was resolved in QGIS 3.6. Now it is possible to control the maximum number of loaded features through *maxEntriesRelationWidget* key in gui global setting. For example in python code:

```
QgsSettings().setValue('gui/maxEntriesRelationWidget', '200')
```